# How to save DateField in django

Tags: python, django

I got this error, but I'm not sure why.

> TypeError: 'Daily' object does not support item assignment

here is the code:

```
yesterday = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1)
item['date'] = yesterday
```

**models.py**

```
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I changed

```
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

to

```
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How to save DateField in django?.

Comment: This isn't specific to dates. You can't access any fields on a Django model with the dictionary notation, only the object notation.

Answer (score 2):

```
item.date = yesterday
```

As the error says, Django models do not support item assignments (the [] syntax), but attributes, with the  `.`.